# Telegram PHP Bot that running on cronjob, how to tips

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I need to build a Telegram Bot that creates a poll and the possible answers are the messagges from the last week with a special hashtag.
I am asking some tips to the approach of this.
My way is that I can run a script/bot that parse all messages with that hastag and date period and creates the poll, I googled but I think there is no api to retrieve old messages, so when I run it example on sunday there is no way to retrieve the past messagse. So a way can be save all the messages (parsing real time and if they contains the hashtag, saves to the db) and when I run the cron I pull the messages form the db itself not the real telegram chat. Can be the smartest way?

I already  know how to build the "hello world" first part of the bot.

Answer (score 0):

Yours is the simplest way to do it. You can use the code below to search a string (in this case an hashtag) in the entire message and then store it in the database.

```php
if (stripos($telegram_message_text, "#toSearch") !== false) {
  //Save message in the database
}
```